# Mp3 with audio tag does not work in safari

Tags: html, safari, wordpress-theming, html5-audio

I am trying to use  tag to play mp3 in a page. The website is based on WordPress. The audio players do not appear in safari but working others browser.

This is the page url: http://soundhealingcenter.com/love/braintests/

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="http://soundhealingcenter.com/online/BetaA.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 3):

The audio players * do appear*  in Safari, and the audio can be played back properly. It just seems that all audio is loaded simulataneously, and since each one is about 20 minutes, that takes a lot of time, also depending on connection speed. In my case, the second one finished loading first, then 4, 5, 9, 10. The others are still loading (and can't be started yet therefore).

So you might want to consider deactivating the automatic loading on page load by adding the attribute `preload="none"` to the `audio` tag, so that would be

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source src="http://soundhealingcenter.com/online/BetaA.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a issue like this and by preload attr in audio tag fixed it.
Since my audio files are small, i used preload = auto. Safari will start playback only once the complete audio is downloaded.Here is my Ref:https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/OxPaVb.You can Refer here for more about preload tag:https://html.com/attributes/audio-preload/

```
Thanks!
```