# HTML audio tag do not work on SAFARI how to fix it

Tags: html, audio, safari, stream, mp3

I try to stream audio from server http://185.34.28.166:8000/;stream.mp3
and when i play on Chrome or Mozilla it work good but when i play this audio on Safari i see loading circle and nothing play. I tried with all formats .mp3, `.wav`, also `.ogg` (i know that this format `.ogg` is not supported by safari). Below code and image how looks like not working audio in safari

```html
<audio class="kopageAudio" controls="">
    <source src="http://185.34.28.166:8000/;stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje znacznika audio.
        </font>
    </font>
</audio>
```

[image]

I try all formats and many parameters in  tag
I would like to correctly play stream in audio tag on website

Comment: There's something wrong with the actual source stream URL.

Comment: Note that the `<font>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 15 years or more.

Answer (score 2):

Your source is of the wrong type.

```
type="audio/mp3"
```

It should be:

```
type="audio/mpeg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the attribute `preload="none"` as suggested on this post?

[Mp3 with audio tag does not work in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896656/mp3-with-audio-tag-does-not-work-in-safari)

Comment: I add this like and also do not work:
  '<audio autoplay="muted" class="kopageAudio" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source src="http://185.34.28.166:8000/;stream.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="http://185.34.28.166:8000/;stream.ogg">
    <source src="http://185.34.28.166:8000/;stream.aac">
    <source src="~http://185.34.28.166:8000/;stream.wav">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje znacznika audio.
        </font>
    </font>
</audio>'

Comment: Why do you use the deprecated `<font>` tag? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp